# Remove a file from invalidation [Amazon AWS CloudFront]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I set a file for "Invalidation" using Amazon AWS CloudFront a few months ago.

Is there any way to remove it rather than duplicating it and naming it differently?

Answer (score 13):

Once the invalidation is completed, it is no longer effective. It then essentially becomes an audit log entry. So you do not need to delete it.

Comment: does new object gets recached after invalidation gets completed ?

Comment: Yes, it does. @yash

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the functionality is not available, through AWS API, CLI, SDKs and Web Console to remove an invalidation. Which means you cannot do it at the moment.

Comment: I think this may be a misunderstanding.  I think OP has an *old* invalidation still showing in the console and assumes that this still has some kind of impact on the object.

Comment: Ah ok you mean there is an invalidation progressing shown? or you see a record of past invalidation happend which you need to remove?

Comment: I believe he sees a "Completed" invalidation in the console, and thinks that this is somehow interfering with the current object, which it wouldn't.

Comment: It would have been a good idea for completed invalidations to have a "completed" or "done" next to them, this was also unclear to me.